# How to simplify this tuple reconstruction?

Tags: python, tuples

For example:

```
tup = (1, 'a', 2, True)
```

I want to add one more element to the `tup` at the end:

```
new_tup = (tup[0], tup[1], tup[2], tup[3], False)
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either concatenate `tup` with a single element(`(False,)`) tuple or unpack the `tup` into a new tuple with unpacking operator `*` :

```py
tup = (1, "a", 2, True)
new_tup1 = tup + (False,)
new_tup2 = (*tup, False)  # You don't have to use parenthesis here.
print(new_tup1)
print(new_tup2)
```

output:

```
(1, 'a', 2, True, False)
(1, 'a', 2, True, False)
```

**Note:** You can only create new tuple objects as they are immutable objects you can't *add* or generally modify them in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tuples together which returns a single tuple of all the elements.

```py
tup = (1, 'a', 2, True)
new_tup = tup + (False,) # put the False like this so it is a tuple to add to the previous.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def addToTup(t, e):
    return t + (e,)


tup = (1, 'a', 2, True)

d = addToTup(tup, False)
print(d)
```

Or you can use `tup = tup.__add__((False,))`